# How to filter rows before and after a certain period (date)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My objective is to select dates before/after a certain period. I have a start period and an end period. I want to filter rows where `close_time` is included between two periods (and some other filters, like category and origin): `start period <= close_time >= end period`.

I have tried using:

```
var StartTime == '2017-03-14'
var EndTime == '2017-03-14'

val df1 = df.withColumn(
  "X_Field", 
  when($"category" === "incident" and $"origin" === "phone" and StartTime <== $"close_time" >== EndTime, 1).otherwise(0)
)
```

I have errors. What is the right syntax to do this ? Thx !

Comment: can you show some sample by doing df.show(false)? and what are the errors you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - unlike with equality, the right operators to use for greater-or-equal and little-or-equal are `<=` and `>=` and not `<==` and `>==`.

Second, the expression `StartTime <= $"close_time" >= EndTime` is not valid - the first part (`StartTime <= $"close_time"`) evaluates into a *Boolean* condition, which you then try to compare to another *String* (`>= EndTime`).

Instead, you can use `between`:

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("X_Field", when(
  $"category" === "incident" and 
    $"origin" === "phone" and 
    ($"close_time" between (StartTime, EndTime)), 1).otherwise(0)
)
```

Which is simply shorthand for:

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("X_Field", when(
  $"category" === "incident" and
    $"origin" === "phone" and
    ($"close_time" >= StartTime and $"close_time" <= EndTime), 1).otherwise(0)
)
```